# How can I restart DataNucleus within a single JVM run?

Tags: java, unit-testing, datanucleus

I'm writing tests for my database access and tend to start them by destroying the database file, then adding data, and having the tests run. (This is to test my business logic--I trust the DataNucleus code implicitly.)

My tests kept passing on the first run and then failing for each subsequent run. This makes no sense, except that I tend to run my tests within the SBT command prompt, which runs everything in one very long-lived JVM instance. At some point I added a setting to fork a new JVM for tests, and everything started working, every time.

What I finally figured out (I think...) is that DataNucleus had initialized itself for the JVM and had created a cache and a view of the environment. When I deleted the database file, the system had no way to know that it needed to reinitialize and re-create everything, because the JVM hadn't stopped and it had no reason to know that I had changed things behind its back.

Clearly, forking a new JVM for tests solves the problem, but I'm wondering if there's a less extreme solution. Basically, is there some way to tell the DataNucleus system to reinitialize? The cleanest thing is probably a `shutdown()` kind of method I could call at the end of my unit tests, but something like `reinitialize()` or `reload()` that I could call at the beginning would also work.

I did try calling `close()` on the `PersistenceManagerFactory`, but that doesn't seem to forget enough stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing and creating a new PMF works for me, since it creates a new StoreManager which creates a connection pool to the datastore (wherever it is). The log would tell you where connections to the datastore are started and ended, and where connection pools are initialised

Comment: I changed my test fixture to use `SchemaAwareStoreManager.delete` and `create` and now everything seems to work. Unfortunately, I changed some other stuff at the same time, so it's unclear if I wasn't closing the `PersistenceManagerFactory` correctly or I was doing something else. Regardless, closing the `PersistenceManagerFactory` does work. Thanks!